# Greater than statement in PHP with query select

Tags: php

How to check if a value is higher that another value when handling with queries?
i got following statement, but it doesnt work.

It seems to run the code no mather what.

```
if (mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT coins FROM klassegrupper WHERE klassegruppe='". $login_session ."'") >= 1) {
```

Comment: What do you expect `mysqli_query` to return? It certainly isn't returning a count.

Comment: an integer value from the database. they varies from -20 to 100

Comment: If you only want to run the query if `$login_session >= 1` is that you have to put that condition in the if statement and the query in the code blocks

Comment: i haven also tried with COUNT(coins), but it doesnt work

Comment: You actually need to get the result of the query and test against that. Trying to execute a query in a conditional statement may be clever, but that code would not be maintainable.

Comment: i want to return some code if the query is higher than 1 where there username = username (thats basicly the query in danish )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_result`. You need to query that object to get the actual "data",

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT coins FROM klassegrupper WHERE klassegruppe='". $login_session ."'");
$coins = $result->fetch_object();
if ($coins->coins >= 1) {
   // ....
}
```

You should also error-check the reuslt of `mysqli_query`. See the example at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the result from the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query
          ($conn,"SELECT coins FROM klassegrupper WHERE klassegruppe='". $login_session ."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];
if ($count >= 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query is not returning the value of 'coins', but a query resource.

Do the following:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT coins FROM klassegrupper WHERE klassegruppe='". $login_session ."'");
$m = mysqli_fetch_assoc["coins"];
if ($m >= 1) {
    // your code here
}
```

This will probably work!